# 入門Goプログラミングのクイックチェック3-6で毎回Launch Failedになる

Tags: go

入門Goプログラミングのクイックチェック3-6で、以下のコードを実行するのですが、毎回Launch Failedになって、Liftoffが出力されません。
どこが間違えているのでしょうか？

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var count = 10

    for count > 0 {
        fmt.Println(count)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if rand.Intn(100) == 0 {
            break
        }
        count--
    }
    if count == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Liftoff")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Launch Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: 「1秒ごとに1/100の確率で打ち上げのカウントダウンを停止させる」という仕様で、当該の書籍に掲載されている通りです。でも、書籍に掲載されているコードでは random seed を初期化していないのです。初期化処理を追加すると、めでたく Lift off します。

Comment: Github で公開されているコードでは修正されていますね。[get-programming-with-go/launch.go at master](https://github.com/nathany/get-programming-with-go/blob/master/lesson03/launch/launch.go)

Comment: 「入門Goプログラミング」です。混乱させてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。@metropolis さんの仰るとおり初期化処理を追加したら、上手くいきました。ありがとうございました。githubの共有もありがとうございます。質問の前にこちらを見ておくべきでした。

Comment: @metropolis さん、回答としてご投稿いただけませんか？